# Convert mailmerge template from MUSTACHE syntax to MERGEFIELD tags

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.words

I would like to allow users to **convert mailmerge templates from MUSTACHE syntax to MERGEFIELD** tags.

Can I achieve this using Aspose for .NET somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use following code example to convert MUSTACHE syntax to MERGEFIELD tags. Hope this helps you.

```
Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(MyDir + "in.docx");
doc.MailMerge.UseNonMergeFields = true;
doc.MailMerge.Execute(new string[] { "" }, new string[] { "" });
doc.Save(MyDir + "Out.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: Thanks Tahir! Basically it doesnt support lots of options so it's fine for simple fields but not for IFs etc.

How I can achieve support of IF statements?

Comment: Could you please share your input and expected output Word documents? I will then provide you more information on this along with code. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.